# fixing the y scale in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to draw multiple bar plots with the same y-scale, and so I need the y-scale to be consistent.
For this, I tried using ylim() after yscale()

**plt.yscale("log")**

**plt.ylim(top=2000)**

**plt.show()**

However, python keeps autoscaling the intermittent values depending on my data.
Is there a way to fix this?

[overlayed graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMhxc.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xaxis = np.arange(10)
yaxis = np.random.rand(10)*100
fig = plt.subplots(figsize =(10, 7))
plt.bar(xaxis, yaxis, width=0.8, align='center', color='y')

# show graph
plt.yscale("log")
plt.ylim(top=2000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please share a [mre]

Comment: Edit your question (and format as code), don't put that in an unreadable comment.

Comment: @Julien took a while to figure out the formatting but I did as you suggested!

Comment: Fix both top and bottom ylim? e.g. `plt.ylim(1,1000)`

Comment: Hi @Garrett - the code above ran fine and did not give multiple y-axes. Is this code correct and complete?

Comment: @Julien I also tried having both bottom and top limits, but it gives a bit of a different scale than the yscale("log"), where the distance between tenfolds are regular. I hoped there might be a way to not do this, because half my bars have similar expression rates and the results are not as visible with plt.ylim(top, bottom). But I guess that's the only way to go. Thanks

Comment: @Redox Just reran to double-check! I get different scales, as in the figure I added "overlayed graphs".

Comment: @Garrett "it gives a bit of a different scale" I don't see how this could be if you use `plt.ylim(bottom, top)`, (which can be used along `yscale("log")`). Share a [mre]...

Answer (score -1):

You can set the y-axis tick labels manually. See [yticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html) for an example. In your case, you will have to do this for each plot to have consistent axes.